# iOS 8,9 font-weight on body element causes html entity &#8209; to disappear (non breaking hyphen)

Tags: html, ios, css

I am using iOS (multiple versions) and when using the html entity `&#8209;` with a font-weight value on the body tag I have the following results:

iOS 9.0.1 (doesn't render entity)

iOS 9.0 (doesn't render entity)

iOS 8.4 (shows odd character below):

[image: iOS 8.4]

Code to reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style>
body 
{
  font-weight: 300;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <span>&#8209;$7.00</span>                                        
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove font-weight it works as expected in all iOS versions. Is this a bug? This bug does NOT happen on Safari for mac

URL to try:
http://chrismuench.com/ios_9_font_bug.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&ndash;` as I have not seen `&#8209;` used previously.

I have tested `&ndash;` on both my IOS devices and the IOS Simulator and both work.

For a full list of html safe characters please see [This site](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

Comment: What does it mean by safe characters?

Comment: Also I don't like the way &ndash looks compared to &#8209;. &#8209; is a non breaking hyphen which I need it to do that.

Comment: If you want the span to be non breaking use `white-space:nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

It appears font-weight for certain fonts can only be 400 or 700 as described here:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/

Common fonts like Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, etc. do not have weights other than 400 and 700. So the same demo displayed with one of those fonts would display only two weights in the nine paragraphs.